# Turning on/off a function by user

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, user-interface, option-type

I have a code using some functions:

```
def 1(...):
    return ....

def 2(...):
    return ....

def 3(...):
    return ....
```

at the end of program we have an equation that the above functions are used in it. How we can give the user an option similar to the following which I show, to choose which function should be used?

I want something like this

```
#for using a function write T and for stopping its usage write F
Use 1 = F
Use 2 = T
Use 3 = T
```

so function 1 is turned off and functions 2 and 3 are turned on and used in the code.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What is your question: How to create the UI with printing and input or how to create and process a function `x` from user's choice?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Dear Michael, as I mentioned, I want to give the user an option to choose from the first which one of function should be use in the code. Because we have very complicated functions and too many of them, we cannot go and remove one by one.

Comment: Yes, but what aspect of that are you having trouble with? Do you not know how to ask for user input? Do you not know how to make decisions based on the input received? Do you not know how to "turn off" a function? (If it's the last one, you're going to have to specify your requirements a lot more precisely than "turn off" first.)

Comment: I think you will have to keep clarifying. Are there any precedence issue ? Priority in the equations ? I have a solution in mind to make you add all your functions together. But you said something about add, sub, mul and div in your question. Yes, what about those ? How will it be decided if I've got to add, sub, mul or div ?

Comment: I gave a simple example in the the answer I poster below, I hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary and allow the user to select a function

```
def vash(x):
    return x + 1
def the(x):
    return x * 2
def stampede(x):
    return pow(x, 3)

d = {'vash': vash, 'the': the, 'stampede': stampede}     
x = 2

print('Which functions to turn on: \n\tvash: add 1 \n\tthe: double, \n\tstampede: raise to 3rd power')
on = []
while True:
    choice = input('Enter function to turn on ("exit" when finished): ')
    if choice == 'exit':
        break
    if choice not in d.keys():
        print('Not a valid function.')
        continue
    on.append(choice)

for i in on:
    x = d[i](x)
    print(x)
```

> ```
> Which functions to turn on: 
>   vash: add 1 
>   the: double, 
>   stampede: raise to 3rd power
> Enter function to turn on ("exit" when finished): vash
> Enter function to turn on ("exit" when finished): blah
> Not a valid function.
> Enter function to turn on ("exit" when finished): the
> Enter function to turn on ("exit" when finished): exit
> 3
> 6
> ```

Comment: Thank you, let me explain a little bit. we have a code with 10000 lines. Inside of this code we have more than 10 functions. Which one of these 10 function sshould be used in the whole code? we dont know, it will be decided by the user. If user turns 1, 4,6,7 on, so we have a code using these functions and other functions are out of use. If the user turns 8, 9 10, we have a code using function 8 9 10 and other functions are off.

Comment: @Ehsan I got you, one moment

Comment: @Ehsan how about this

Comment: thank you, I think it will work. Indeed all functions do not have similar parameters. def1(x,y,z), def2(x,d,f), def 3( z,r,t)...

Comment: but let me check and I check this post to be answer.

Comment: @Ehsan no prob! hope this helped :)

Comment: is the final equation makes differentiation in code? I mean, in your code at the final stage we have separate out puts. What if we want to plus them? vash + the. or the + stamepede. or even multiplication of them. Also, with different args or parameters in functions.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the answer for each function from your user using input()
Then, you need to use a boolean for each function to allow or block the use of that function:

I think you are looking for smthg like:

```
def function1():
   return 2
def function2():
   return 4
def function3():
   return 6  
use_1 = input("Type T to use 1 ")
use_2 = input("Type T to use 2 ")
use_3 = input("Type T to use 3 ")
x=(use_1=='T')*function1()+(use_2=='T')*function2()+(use_3=='T')*function3()
print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, let me explain a little bit. we have a code with 10000 lines. Inside of this code we have more than 10 functions. Which one of these 10 function sshould be used in the whole code? we dont know, it will be decided by the user. If user turns 1, 4,6,7 on, so we have a code using these functions and other functions are out of use. If the user turns 8, 9 10, we have a code using function 8 9 10 and other functions are off.

Comment: That code above should help you do that, I gave an example with 3 functions but you can extend to 10

Comment: The quanity is not important, jus the way of turning of and on is of utmost importance, dear Amine

Comment: The way of turning on or off is through boolean. In the code above is using (use_1=='T') if it's true then we allow the use if not we don't.

Comment: Yes, Please let me check, and I will check the post as answer. Thank you.

Comment: I edited the code so it's easier to use functions with many arguments